# How to query inheritance Tables in EF Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I got tables / classes like this in my EF Core

```
public class Member 
{
 public int Id {get; set;}
 public string Name {get; set;}
 .. other props
}


public class Employee
{
 public int Id {get; set;}
 public string Name {get; set;}
 .. other props
}


public class Transaction {
  public int Id {get; set;}
  .. other props
 public ICollection<TransactionDetail> Details {get; set;}
}


public class TransactionDetail{  
 public int Id {get; set;}
 public int TransactionId {get; set;}

 public decimal TransactionValue; 
 ... other props
}

public class TransactionDetailMember: TransactionDetail{  
 public int MemberId;
 public Member member;
 ... other props
}


public class TransactionDetailEmployee: TransactionDetail{  
 public int EmployeeId;
 public Employee employee;
 ... other props
}


public class TransactionDetailStranger: TransactionDetail{  
 public string StrangerName;
 ... other props
}
```

I want to record a transaction made by Member, Employee and Stranger (non member & not employee).
How to query this record properly so I can get the Member, Employee and Stranger model/table in my Transaction.Details ? should I made 3 details instead of one ?

I use .NetCore 3 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

First let me suggest a refactoring of your model mapping, instead of having a navigation property in your `TransactioDetail.cs`, let the transaction itself have a full navigation to the `TransactionDetail`. Add

```
public int TransactionDetailId {get; set;}
public TransactionDetail TransactionDetail {get; set;}
```

Since you truncated the `Transaction.cs` file, I don't know if it has a navigation property to an `Employee` or to a `Member`, but a transaction need to have a person who performed it. In that case, if it has, you'll need just to

```
transactionRepository.Get().Include(x => x.TransactionDetail).Include(x => x.Member)
```

Then you can get both the details and the member or employee as the case may be.

Comment: Transaction is like summary of transaction that recorded by the User. So in the detail it could have transaction done by member, employee or strangers. Thats why I have 3 type TransactionDetails. I want to make it as one if possible. If not I may split into 3 Details.

Comment: What does `TransactionDetailMember` and the rest do?

Comment: TransactionDetailMember, TransactionDetailEmployee, TransactionDetailStranger are just for record the transaction details but they are done by different kind of person which is Member, Employee and Stranger